# How to compare and merge two nested dictionaries into another nested dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have two nested dictionaries -

```
Runid1 = { 'test1' : {'r1':6.0, 'r2':1.0, 'r3':3.0, 'r4':116.0, 'r5':80.0},
           'test2' : {'r1':5.0, 'r2':1.0, 'r3':1.0, 'r4':1.0, 'r5':80.0},
           'test3' : {'r1':5.0, 'r2':11.0, 'r3':50.0, 'r4':80.0, 'r5':20.0},
           'test4' : {'r1':7.0 , 'r2':9.0 , 'r3':5.0 , 'r4':1.0 , 'r5':80.0} }

Runid2 = { 'test1' : {'r1':1.0, 'r2':1.0, 'r3':2.0, 'r4':75.0, 'r5':79.0},
           'test5' : {'r1':1.0, 'r2':1.0, 'r3':1.0, 'r4':1.0, 'r5':80.0},
           'test3' : {'r1':2.0, 'r2':10.0, 'r3':45.0, 'r4':60.0, 'r5':80.0},
           'test4' : {'r1':1.0, 'r2':1.0, 'r3':1.0,  'r4':1.0, 'r5':80.0} }
```

Task: for each test in Runid1, if the test is present in Runid2, we compare the two nested dictionaries for that test.

Based on some condition(s), we compare each parameter (r-values) of both the dictionaries and create lists of such parameters, that qualify the condition. We add the result to another dictionary named 'Result'.

Eg. For each test in Runid1, add to list all r values that are < 10 and diff between them is > 4.

```
Result = { 'test1' : {'r1':[6.0,1.0]},
           'test3' : {},
           'test4' : {'r1':[7.0,1.0], 'r2':[9.0,1.0], 'r3':[5.0,1.0]} }
```

Comment: That seems like a homework problem and you haven't shown any attempt. Please include what you've tried so far and where specifically you're having problems.

Comment: Hi- the task was not a homework. I am new to python and couldn't just think of a way to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try looping over the intersecting keys, then adding the results to a dictionary based on your conditions:

```
from pprint import pprint

Runid1 = {
    "test1": {"r1": 6.0, "r2": 1.0, "r3": 3.0, "r4": 116.0, "r5": 80.0},
    "test2": {"r1": 5.0, "r2": 1.0, "r3": 1.0, "r4": 1.0, "r5": 80.0},
    "test3": {"r1": 5.0, "r2": 11.0, "r3": 50.0, "r4": 80.0, "r5": 20.0},
    "test4": {"r1": 7.0, "r2": 9.0, "r3": 5.0, "r4": 1.0, "r5": 80.0},
}

Runid2 = {
    "test1": {"r1": 1.0, "r2": 1.0, "r3": 2.0, "r4": 75.0, "r5": 79.0},
    "test5": {"r1": 1.0, "r2": 1.0, "r3": 1.0, "r4": 1.0, "r5": 80.0},
    "test3": {"r1": 2.0, "r2": 10.0, "r3": 45.0, "r4": 60.0, "r5": 80.0},
    "test4": {"r1": 1.0, "r2": 1.0, "r3": 1.0, "r4": 1.0, "r5": 80.0},
}

result = {}
for key in Runid1.keys() & Runid2.keys():
    result[key] = {}

    for k1, k2 in zip(Runid1[key], Runid2[key]):
        v1, v2 = Runid1[key][k1], Runid2[key][k2]

        if v1 < 10 and v2 < 10 and abs(v1 - v2) >= 4:
            result[key][k1] = [v1, v2]

pprint(result)
```

Which gives the following:

```
{'test1': {'r1': [6.0, 1.0]},
 'test3': {},
 'test4': {'r1': [7.0, 1.0], 'r2': [9.0, 1.0], 'r3': [5.0, 1.0]}}
```

However, the above approach assumes ordering of keys with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which is only guaranteed in **Python3.6+**.

If were using lower versions of Python, then we need to first check if the key from the first dictionary exists in the second dictionary:

```
result = {}
for key in Runid1.keys() & Runid2.keys():
    result[key] = {}

    for k1, v1 in Runid1[key].items():
        if k1 in Runid2[key]:
            v2 = Runid2[key][k1]

            if v1 < 10 and v2 < 10 and abs(v1 - v2) >= 4:
                result[key][k1] = [v1, v2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def cmp_r(r1, r2):
...     return r1 < 10 and r2 < 10 and abs(r1 - r2) >= 4
...
>>> def merge_r(d1, d2):
...     return {k: [v, d2[k]] for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2 and cmp_r(v, d2[k])}
...
>>> Result = {k: merge_r(v, Runid2[k]) for k,v in Runid1.items() if k in Runid2}
>>> Result
{'test1': {'r1': [6.0, 1.0]},
 'test3': {},
 'test4': {'r1': [7.0, 1.0], 'r2': [9.0, 1.0], 'r3': [5.0, 1.0]}}
```